# AngularJS uses document.getElementById to find elements only once

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angularjs

When you click on a particular item, there is a page where the panel appears on the right.

Invokes the Angular JS code to act when the panel is opened.

The Angular JS code is supposed to find an element in an HTML document with an id value of 'view-link'.

However, it only looks for the item when the panel is opened for the first time, and it cannot find the element when the panel is closed and then re-opened.

In developer mode, element lookup is normally performed with the same syntax as the code.

I must refresh (F5) to retrieve it again.

What's the problem?

Considering it as a variable or controller initialization problem, we have configured the link_element_2 variable to initialize if there is no href value for link_element.

The html code you are trying to find is as follows and is always included when the panel is opened.

```
<a id="view-link" href="https://www.google.com">https://www.google.com</a>
```

My code :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
     console.log('widget load!!!');
     var link_element = null;
     var link_element_2 = null;
     console.log(link_element);
     var youtube_link = null;
     console.log(youtube_link);
     
    link_element = angular.element(document.getElementById('view-link'));
    console.log('link_element IS');
    console.log(link_element);
  
    if(link_element.attr('href') == undefined)
    {
        console.log('In if case');
        link_element_2 = angular.element(document.getElementById('view-link'));
        console.log('link_element_2 IS');
        console.log(link_element_2);
    }
        
    $scope.controllerActive = true;
              
    $scope.$on("$destroy", function() {
        $scope.controllerActive = false;
        console.log("Controller destroyed");
    });
 
});
```

The results are as follows.
The screen is a console log in developer mode.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nd9iB.png)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're facing a timing issue. The JavaScript code gets executed before the new DOM elements (introduced when the panel opens) are fully loaded. This results in your script not being able to find the element by its ID since it does not yet exist in the DOM at the time of execution.
To solve this, you should use Angular's $timeout service.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {
     console.log('widget load!!!');
     var link_element = null;
     var link_element_2 = null;
     console.log(link_element);
     var youtube_link = null;
     console.log(youtube_link);
     
     $timeout(function() {
        link_element = angular.element(document.getElementById('view-link'));
        console.log('link_element IS');
        console.log(link_element);
      
        if(link_element.attr('href') == undefined)
        {
            console.log('In if case');
            link_element_2 = angular.element(document.getElementById('view-link'));
            console.log('link_element_2 IS');
            console.log(link_element_2);
        }
     });

     $scope.controllerActive = true;

     $scope.$on("$destroy", function() {
         $scope.controllerActive = false;
         console.log("Controller destroyed");
     });

}]);
```

Let me know if this works.